# Chat with Socket and RxJava

Tags: java, android, sockets, rx-java

I'm creating this chat application where the users can talk when they're connected on same `WiFi`. They detect each others using `Network Service Discovery` (it works very bad, sometimes they doesn't find each other). Once they have seen each other on the network they can start a conversation. I'd created this class:

**code:**

```
public class ChatConnection {

     private ServerSocket serverSocket;
     private Socket socket;
     private InputStream inputStream;
     private OutputStream outputStream;
     private DataInputStream dataInputStream;
     private DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
     private String message = "";

    private Thread serverThread;

    @Inject
    public ChatConnection() {
        serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        serverThread.start();
    }

    public Observable<Boolean> connectToServer(InetAddress host, int port)    
    {
        return Observable.unsafeCreate(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super Boolean> subscriber) {
                 try {
                    if (socket != null) {
                        if (socket.isConnected()) {
                            socket.close();
                        }
                        socket = new Socket(host, port);
                    } else
                        socket = new Socket(host, port);                 

                    subscriber.onNext(socket.isConnected());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                     subscriber.onError(e);                    
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Observable<String> observeServer() {        
         return Observable.unsafeCreate(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
                try {
                    while (!message.equals("##exit##")) {
                        message = dataInputStream.readUTF();
                        subscriber.onNext(message);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    subscriber.onError(e);
                }
        });
    }

    public Observable<Boolean> sendMessage(String message) {
        return Observable.unsafeCreate(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super Boolean> subscriber) {
                try {
                    dataOutputStream.writeUTF(message);
                    subscriber.onNext(true);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    subscriber.onError(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public int getLocalPort() {
        return serverSocket.getLocalPort();
    }

    public void tearDown() {
        try {
            socket.close();
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    class ServerThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(0);
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

The problem is **observeServer()** is not doing anything, even setting Log.d(...) inside never shows anything. I'm very new with `java sockets`. I would like someone tells me what I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Your code is for a server or a client? Before we can tell what you do wrong you should tell what you want to do.

Comment: This class should be used for both things. Two devices and one is server and the other client. I never will know who will be the server or the client, so I need both functionalities: server and client.

Comment: In the constructor of your class a serversocket thread is started. I do not understand why that would be done for a client app.

Comment: what should I do? how the devices decides who's the server and who's the client? remember that **I'm very new with java sockets**

Comment: Start with making two classes. One for a server and one for a client. Deciding which will be the server and who clients is something completely different.  You can do that later when your server and client code are ok.

Comment: Do you know if there's another way to chat between two devices? a peer to peer chat? I don't like so much sockets and that trouble about who's client or server. The client gave the visual interfaces and they're similar to a simple chat app (like whatsapp, facebook), but I think it's complicated this way :( the architecture isn't the same because this has to work without server in the middle.